# Android Google Maps CustomCap appearing behind polyline

Tags: java, android, google-maps, kotlin

I am plotting routes on a Google map in Android with polylines. I wish to have a start cap on my first polyline showing the user where the route begins.

However, when the route I am displaying must be displayed with multiple polylines and the last polyline ends near where the first polyline begins, I am sometimes seeing the start cap displayed behind this last polyline.

This does not occur every time. I would like to ensure that the start cap is always displayed above any and all polylines. How can I ensure that the cap is displayed on top of all polylines?

Here is the method that I am using to draw routes on my map:

```
private fun addRoute(context: Context, map: GoogleMap, mapData: MapData, color: Int) {

            mapData.routeSegments.forEachIndexed { index, segment ->

                val polylineOptions = PolylineOptions()

                segment.points.forEach { point ->

                    polylineOptions.add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude))
                }

                val polyline = map.addPolyline(polylineOptions)

                polyline.isClickable = false
                polyline.color = color
                polyline.width = POLYLINE_WIDTH

                if (index == 0) {
                    val bitmap = DrawableUtil.getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(context, R.drawable.star_red_28px)
                    polyline.startCap = CustomCap(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap))
                }

            }
        }
```

Expected:

[image]

Actual:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Line caps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/shapes#line-caps) specify a [Cap](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Cap) style for each end of a polyline. Seems it displayed on top not of all, but on top of its polyline. So for ensure that the cap is displayed "on top" of all polylines you should [set Z-index](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline.html#setZIndex(float)) for each polyline cumulatively and draw polylines from "global" start to end: in that case `startCap` of next segment overlaps end of current polyline. Or you can not use Caps but use [markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker) with custom `R.drawable.star_red_28px` icon this way:

```
...
LatLng polylineStartLatLng = polyline.getPoints().get(0);

Drawable starDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.star_red_28px);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
starDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 28, 28);
starDrawable.draw(canvas);
BitmapDescriptor markerIcon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(polylineStartLatLng)
        .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
        .icon(markerIcon)
);
...
```

Comment: Thanks, @Andrii. After setting z-index for all polylines not containing the startCap in order to place them "behind" my startCap-containing polyline, it appears my issue is resolved.